# Dll-Injection, call function in target process

Tags: function, dll, find, call, code-injection

I have some basic knowledge about how assembly works and I also know the basics about higher level programming. (I did a lot of ahk and lua.) 
But I never really did object orientated programming.

I did the official Cheat Engine tutorial, so I know how to find static pointers to changeable values and I'm also able to make a program decrement a value instead of incrementing it. And I know that the properties of units in computergames or mostly stored in consecutive addresses...

Well, what I want is to **find** and **call**  **functions** of some of my computergames.
Examples:

- draw pictures and text (the same way the game does it, with the same font etc)
- shoot my gun
- cast my spell to position xy
- buy a new weapon/spell or whatever

I **don't** want to hook directX or simulate keystrokes.

I want to do it in C++ via Dll-Injection.

I don't really know C++, but I could write a function, loop, if statement and declare variables etc (all that basic stuff).

It will probably a bit more complicated, but something like that would be great: a lib/class/function which I could use like this:

```
pointer = [[[[myprocess.exe]+C4]+0]+8]
address = PointerToAddress(pointer)
CallFunction(address) //or CallFunction(address, param1, param2, ...)
```

Comment: Well, to be perfectly honest with you... If you didn't write the game yourself, and you wish to use dll injection but don't wish to hook DirectX or simulate keystrokes, then how would you expect to do anything in that list? It's doubt it's possible. Your application runs in it's own address space, and the target app runs in it's own. And if the target app uses DX to handle it's rendering, then you'll have to utilize it too from *inside* the target process. Furthermore, all of this will take extensive knowledge of C++, method signatures, memory management, etc... Time to rethink your strategy.